# Hombrew is asking me for a version of Xcode the OS doesnt support

Tags: macos, xcode, homebrew

I need to download certain apps through homebrew, one of them being pygtk, but when putting the rather simple command that should install it homebrew says my Xcode (6.4 because I am on Yosemite) is outdated and that need the 7.2.1 which I can't install because it's not supported in Yosemite. How can I fix this?

Comment: Macports has different versions for each OSX version for this and other reasons so if Homebrew does not have this set of separate releases then you are out of luck,

Comment: Thank you, I will look up if homebrew has different versions for different OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may mean that you can't install pygtk through homebrew on Yosemite. You may still be able to compile from source, even with your version of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find a way to do that, was hoping that there was a fix since it's not with just that app that the error appears. I guess I am out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-8-and-get-the-dmg-file/10335943#10335943) on stackoverflow which tells us Xcode 7.2.1 is the last support Xcode for Yosemite and supplies a URL for those with a developer account ([Xcode_7.2.1.dmg](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.2.1/Xcode_7.2.1.dmg)). The URL appears to be valid (starts a download). I've used Xcode 7.2 on Yosemite.